# WaitForSeconds unity malfunction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I searched and there are bunch of topics about that, however I cannot identify a logic behind my problem.

I have a code in which I do:

```
    void OnBecameInvisible(){

    StartCoroutine (espera ());

}

IEnumerator espera(){

    jovem = Random.Range (10, 20);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (jovem);



    Instantiate (seta, new Vector3 (4.4f, 8.16f, 0), transform.localRotation);


    Destroy (this.gameObject);
}
```

and that works fine, so in another script I tried to do:

```
void OnBecameInvisible(){

    StartCoroutine (espera ());
    xiz = Random.Range (-0.9f, 16.0f);

    Instantiate (rodaroda, new Vector3(xiz,yiz,0), transform.localRotation);

    Destroy (this.gameObject);
}

IEnumerator espera(){

    jovem = Random.Range (1, 15);
    Debug.Log ("tempo" + jovem);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (jovem);



}
```

So I understood that the Wait for seconds only works if I use only it in the section... Could Anyone explain how to solve this problem of being able to use something with the waitforseconds?

edit:::

To clarify:  If i use only the waitforseconds subroutine in the section of the script it works fine and counts the time correclty, if U put something else there it just ignores the subroutine...

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I tried to clarify I little bit more